# How to rotate Image and Rectangle

Tags: java, swt

how to rotate a rectangle in canvas?

for example.

```
Rectangle Box = new Rectangle(100,100,100,100);
```

and i want to rotate this by (for example)38 degres.

Someone know how i can do it?

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://jexp.ru/index.php/Java_Tutorial/SWT_2D_Graphics/Transform

Comment: See [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html)

Comment: Although you've tagged this question as SWT, you might want to edit the content to make it clear that this relates to SWT and not AWT or Swing.

Comment: @david i know it, i use SWT